# Syntax difference in Python lists assignment results in implicit variable substitution

Tags: python, list, variable-assignment

Novice question here. I'm confused as to why, only under certain syntax, a list is *automatically* updated when the other list it's assigned to gets updated. For example,

If we assign 'a' to 'b' and update 'b', 'a' remains unaffected:

```
>>> b = [1,1,0]
>>> a = b
a = [1,1,0]
>>> b = [0,0,0]
a = [1,1,0]
```

However, if we re-write the last update command as:

```
>>> b[:2] = [0]*2
a = [0,0,0]
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `a` and `b` are *references* to objects. When you write:

```
a = b
```

Then `a` and `b` are **referencing the same object**, so when you modify it acting on `b`, also `a` will change. If they where pointers (and, under the hood, they are), they would be *pointing to the same object*.

When you write:

```
b[:2] = [0, 0] # [0] * 2
```

you are *modifying* the list, so changes will reflect in `a`.

Instead, when you write:

```
b = [0,0,0]
```

`b` will be referencing a new, different list and changes will not reflect in`a`.

Answer (score 2):

When you do a simple assignment like `b = [0,0,0]`, you are creating a *new* list object in memory and changing `b` to point to that *new* list object. This has no bearing on `a` which may point to some other location (including where `b` used to point, as is the case here).

When you assign to a slice like in `b[:2] = [0]*2`, you are doing an in-place modification, hence the the change can be seen through any pointer pointing also to `b`'s list. In this case, that means `a` as well.

For example, consider a slight modification of your first snippet:

```
>>> b = [1,1,0]
>>> a = b
>>> b[:] = [0,0,0]
>>> 
>>> a
[0, 0, 0]
>>> b
[0, 0, 0]
```

Notice that now `a` *and* `b` appear modified, since assigning to `b[:]` modifies the list pointed to by `b` in-place and, since `a` points to *that same* list, we can see the change through `a` as well. Again, this is in contrast to your first snippet, where `b` is being redirected to point to a new object altogether.

Comment: Makes sense. Follow up question: after b is reassigned to [0,0,0], what happens to the memory that stored the object that contains [1,1,0]? Is it wiped clean and reusable at this point?

Comment: @user1211129 That's more of an implementation detail. In CPython, yes, it will be [garbage collected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) (`free`d) and made reusable.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: CPython uses reference counting (in addition to the optional GC that runs periodically), and will actually cleanup objects with no references to them immediately.

Comment: Another question: If I make list 'b', but then want to make a copy 'a' of that list. How do I preserve the copy if 'b' undergoes further manipulation?

Comment: @user1211129 To copy a list you can simply use `b = list(a)`.